# Create a new column based on the state of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I want to create a new column that counts the number of days since the state was 1. As an example, the current columns would be the first three below. The forth column is what I'm trying to get.

```
Index State Days Since_Days
  1     1    0       0
  2     0    20      20
  3     0    40      40
  4     1    55      55
  5     1    60       5
  6     1    70      10
```

Without resorting to for-loop, what is a pandas way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values to be subtracted can be formed with:

```
ser = df['Days'].where(df['State']==1, np.nan).ffill().shift()
```

If you subtract this from the original Days column, you'll have:

```
df['Days'].sub(ser, fill_value=0).astype('int')
Out: 
0     0
1    20
2    40
3    55
4     5
5    10
Name: Days, dtype: int64
```

Comment: For being the first

Answer (score 3):

You can also try following where first you group by `State` and for those that have `State == 1`, fill by difference. Then, for those which has `State == 0` will be `na` which can be filled by corresponding `Days` column value

```
df.loc[df.State == 1, 'Since_Days'] = df.groupby('State')['Days'].diff().fillna(0)
df['Since_Days'].fillna(df['Days'],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Index  State  Days  Since_Days
0      1      1     0         0.0
1      2      0    20        20.0
2      3      0    40        40.0
3      4      1    55        55.0
4      5      1    60         5.0
5      6      1    70        10.0
```